# when using datasource and databind to set items in a dropdownlist - index is always the value of first item

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to use datasource and bind in my application to set a dropdown list to the results of a query. The dropdownlist populates correctly (shows each different type_name in the set) but later when I use ddltype.selectedvalue - I am always getting the value from the first item in the dataset. Here is the code.

```
        if ds.hasRows = true
        ddlType.DataValueField = "type_id"
        ddlType.DataTextField = "type_name"
        ddlType.DataSource = ds
        ddlType.DataBind()
        end if
```

Then later on I use the following code to try to get teh selected value

```
        Dim typeID = ddlType.SelectedValue
```

I have ran the query to get the dataset on my SQL server and get the below results - but every time I use the above dim statement, the value is set to 812 even when type 2 is selected. Below is the results from the query that fills the sqldatareader named ds.

```
type_id : type_name
___________________
812     : type one

813     : type two
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the rendered SQL to make sure the html is correct.  Is someone actually selecting the item and it is not being reselected/reset in code?

Comment: Are you checking the value of `ddlType.SelectedValue` in a `Button.Click` handler or something similar?  Please post the full code showing this part, and markup for both the ddl and submit control.  Also, where does the databinding code you posted occur?  Does it run on every post back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information in your question,  I don't see anything wrong.

But based on common mistakes people make with this pattern, I am guessing you are probably running `ddlType.DataBind()` on every postback.  So the user clicks a button or something similar to fire the postback, and the DDL is re-bound before your click handler checks the value.  Re-binding sets the selectedvalue back to default.

Edit: Your databinding code in Page_Load should only run once.  One way to do this is to wrap the databinding code...

```
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        If ds.hasRows = True Then
            ddlType.DataValueField = "type_id"
            ddlType.DataTextField = "type_name"
            ddlType.DataSource = ds
            ddlType.DataBind()
        End If
    End If
```

This will cause the databinding to occur only the first time the page is requested, but not after a button click or other postback action.

Comment: The databind is ran on page load. The ddltype.selected value is ran when a button is clicked. could this be an issue? I do this on another page in my application but it is working correctly.

Comment: you were corrected, I added an if for no ispost back and it works. Thank you.